# CSS negative percentage left position not working as expected

Tags: css

I have a container that uses `width:90%;` to create gutters on the left and right. Within the container, I would like the first child to use up the full width of the screen(ignoring the gutters). To do this I am using `width:100vw` and `left:-5%`. I would expect that this would make the child element take up the full viewport width and start at the very edge of the left side of the screen, but there is a small sliver of the gutter visible to the left. Is it possible to make it line up with the left edge perfectly?

```css
body,html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.outer-container {
  width:100vw;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

.image-container {
  position:relative;
}
  .image-container:first-child {
    width:100vw;
    left:-5%;
  }

img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/501/500/500.jpg?hmac=LexAc6tjpzq0VN8f7zj8JNiU6vcLhPTqSX17dsaXP3o" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/193/500/500.jpg?hmac=5eXseIVa0Mq_-eotbpTeHTABeV-agyM79NghBnEmCJw" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/835/500/500.jpg?hmac=QnpnNG0BSK7JQNhA9VokyFMyhTwTtifkHYHWSsd2YAU" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body,html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.outer-container {
  width:100vw;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

.image-container {
  position:relative;
}
.image-container:first-child {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

img {
  width:100%;
}
.inner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/501/500/500.jpg?hmac=LexAc6tjpzq0VN8f7zj8JNiU6vcLhPTqSX17dsaXP3o" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/193/500/500.jpg?hmac=5eXseIVa0Mq_-eotbpTeHTABeV-agyM79NghBnEmCJw" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/835/500/500.jpg?hmac=QnpnNG0BSK7JQNhA9VokyFMyhTwTtifkHYHWSsd2YAU" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am sorry.I forgot to add one more style to the css.

```
.inner-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;}
```

please add this code also and try

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below css. Don't need **left:-5%;** Hope this helps.

```
.image-container:first-child {
width: 100vw;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;}
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately without the `left:-5%;` the box starts 5% in from the left due to the `90%` width of the parent element.